# Seeking examples of complementary distribution of [s] and [ʃ] in Japanese

Tags: phonology, japanese, compl-distribution

`[s]` & `[ʃ]` are in complementary distribution within Japanese as I already know, but I don't speak Japanese and I'm finding it difficult to give examples how they are in distribution, are there any examples which could work?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE. While this is definitely a linguistics-related question, because you're asking specifically for Japanese you might get a better response over on [Japanese Language & Culture](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/?as=1). Although language-specific questions are allowed here sometimes, we generally try to avoid them.

Comment: Incidentally, I study Korean, not Japanese, but I believe they both treat `[s]` and `[ʃ]` the same way. Specifically, `[s] -> [ʃ] / __[i]`. Compare the Japanese for "three", `[san]`, with the Japanese for "four", `[ʃi]`. I believe `[si]` and `[ʃan]` are both unattested in Japanese (this is the case for Korean). Additionally, in Korean the same change is triggered by the approximate `[j]`. I'd suggest having a Japanese speaker confirm if this is the case in Japanese too.

Comment: Assuming that by [ʃ], you mean [ɕ], the unvoiced alveolopalatal sibilant, [ɕ] and [s] are *not* in complementary distribution. One minimal pair is [ɕaiɴ] "company employee" and [ɕaiɴ] "signature".

Comment: This was all really helpful, thanks! Also sorry for the wrong area, I should have oriented my question to phonetics more than Japanese. Thanks again!

Comment: @dainichi, I'm sure this is obvious to most people, but you meant [saiɴ] for "signature", of course...

Comment: @musicallinguist, whoops, yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @acattle, Ben Shahn in Korean seems to be 벤샨. How would you transcribe this?

Comment: @dainichi It turns out that like Japanese, Korean doesn't have `[ʃ]`, it has `[ɕ]`. As I mentioned, the [`[s] -> [ɕ]`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Korean#cite_note-11) rule can be triggered by the approximate `[j]`. While the `[a]` is written in Korean as ㅏ, ㅑ (with an extra horizontal line) represents `[ja]`. Thus 벤샨 would be `[pen ɕjan]`. Using `[i]` and `[j]` to approximate pronunciation of `[ʃ]` in loanwords, e.g. "rush" as 러시, `[rʌɕi]`, is a pretty common strategy. It also affects loanwords containing `[si]` combinations such as "sing" becoming 씽, `[ɕ͈iŋ]`.

Comment: @acattle, my point in asking about 샨 was that I assumed it is pronounced [ɕan] and not [ɕjan], thereby contradicting your "unattested" claim. I'm not much of a phonologist, but I assume you could argue for some analysis by which the /j/ forces the s->ɕ after which the /j/ is lost by elision.

Comment: @acattle: I don't know if it's still the case, but Japanese Language & Usage had some prominent users who were more than a little hostile to linguistic questions. It's the main reason I lost interest in the site.

Comment: I think it is pretty much full of linguistics questions now :P

Answer (score 7):

As has been noted in the comments, [s] and [ɕ] (sometimes broadly transcribed as [ʃ]) are not in complementary distribution in Japanese. However, they *can* be analyzed as allophones of the same phoneme.

The following rule can be used to explain some of the facts:

/s/ --> [ɕ] before [i], [s] elsewhere

```
[asa] 'morning'
[ɕi] 'four'
[aɕi] 'foot'
[isu] 'chair'
[seki] 'cough'
[heso] 'belly button'
```

However, [ɕ] also appears before other vowels besides [i]:

```
[iɕa] 'doctor'
[hoɴɕuː] 'Honshu'
[ɕoːyu] 'soy sauce'
```

This leads to an analysis in which it is sensible to treat /ɕ/ as its own phoneme.

Not counting the less nativized loanword pronunciations of words (like [siː] for the English letter 'C'), we never get [s] before [i]. Related forms like [osu] 'press-PRESENT' and [oɕita] 'press-PAST' give us further evidence that at least some instances of [ɕ] before [i] are likely surface realizations of /s/.

So, one analysis that captures all of the facts is that there are two phonemes--/s/, which has the allophones [s] and [ɕ], and /ɕ/, which always surfaces as [ɕ].

EDIT: In response to comments below, here is an alternative analysis that can also capture the facts:

We observe that palatalized versions of consonants may appear before [a], [o], and [u]:

```
[kʲoku] 'piece of music'
[nʲuːiɴ] 'hospitalization'
[ɾʲoːhoː] 'both'
[hʲaku] 'one hundred'
[happʲaku] 'eight hundred'
[sambʲaku] 'three hundred'
[bimʲoː] 'subtle'
```

(The choice of transcription of these Cʲ onsets varies; some choose to use [ç] instead of [hʲ], for example.)

There are some gaps--the alveolar stops ([t], [d]), alveolar fricatives ([s], and [z]), and the bilabial approximant [w] do not have palatalized counterparts. The [w] gap is not an unexpected one, since [w] is the only approximant (besides [j] itself). Historically, the palatalized counterparts of [t], [d], [s], and [z] became what are now the alveolo-palatal consonants [tɕ], [dʑ], [ɕ], and [ʑ], respectively. Further, these alveolo-palatal consonants do not have palatalized counterparts (there is no [ɕ]/[ɕʲ] contrast, for example).

Due to the above facts, some consider it reasonable to adopt a synchronic analysis in which all surface occurrences of [tɕ] and [dʑ] are underlyingly /tʲ/ and /dʲ/, respectively, and all surface occurrences of [ɕ] and [ʑ] are underlyingly /sʲ/ and /tʲ/ (or even /sj/ and /tj/), respectively.

Comment: As far as I know, [ɕ] other than before [i] is restricted to loanwords (including _ongaku_ readings of Chinese morphemes, some of which have been in Japanese for a very long time). Certainly all three examples above are _ongaku_.

Comment: [muʃi] [ase] [miso] [toʃi] [muʃi] - I've been given these examples and thus far the only thing I can think to explain is that [ʃ] occurs before closed front & central vowels. It might be that I have been explicitly told that they are in complementary distribution, but this isn't clicking in my head.

Comment: Could you also analyse it such that any instance of [ɕ] before not-/i/ is underlyingly /sj/ or /sʲ/?

Comment: @ColinFine that would make sense, but some would shrug that off as a historical accident that is irrelevant for synchronic analyses.

Comment: @Sjiveru actually, the occurrence of [ɕ] before non-[i] vowels does derive historically from /s/+/j/. One could adopt such an analysis to explain the data synchronically, but it is unclear how one would justify the existence of an underlying /j/ that never surfaces.

Comment: @musicallinguist Perhaps by analogy to other similar /Cj/ sequences? I don't know, I find it quite difficult myself to draw the line between synchronic phonological processes and diachronic explanations.

Comment: @Dominic all it takes is one minimal pair to undermine a claim of complementary distribution, haha! Your only recourse would be to explain away all of the apparent minimal pairs as exceptions, but more than likely you'd have to draw distinctions that are historically motivated, as discussed in the comments here.

Comment: I strongly think that [ɕ] is underlying /sj/. Otherwise, the syllable /sjV/ would not exist, while all other /CjV/ exist. Also, perhaps this is due to me not having Awesome English Ears that think [ɕ] sounds even remotely like [ʃ] (ugh their anglophone Japanese accents!), but [ɕ] really is acoustically very close to [sj], and [ɕ] is really "/s/ before palatals". Note that [ɕj] sounds identical to [ɕ]; [ʃj] sounds very different from [ʃ]; I in fact perceive [ɕV] naturally as [ɕjV], as a consonant cluster. (FYI my L1 is Mandarin)

Comment: Further supporting this is that if you treat [ɕ] as [ɕj], then there are no exceptions at all to "/s/ becomes [ɕ] before palatals." Japanese natives also have terrible trouble pronouncing [sj] and [si] without palatalizing the [s].

Comment: @user54609, I've added an alternative analysis in response to your comments.

Comment: @Sjiveru I've added an alternative analysis in response to your comments.